# java script coding error? cant get cell contents to match

Tags: javascript, excel

i have been working on a work project. i want to find out from a set of cell ranges if within a certain date range are a certain store and then count how many times that store shows up inside the range.  i have the formula mostly working. but when i compare the store to the unique values in the range it does not match even though the input for the first value and the second are the same.

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function () {
    var u = {}, a = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        a.push(this[i]);
        u[this[i]] = 1;
    }

  return a;
}   
    function countOnDate(datestart,dateend,daterange,sheet,valuesrange){
      var datestart = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datestart), "GMT+1", "M/d/yyy")
      var dateend = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateend), "GMT+1", "M/d/yyy")
      var range = sheet.getRange(daterange).getValues();
      var countrange = sheet.getRange(valuesrange).getValues()
      var count = [];
      var countrangeunique = countrange.getUnique()
      //Logger.log("countrange:"+countrange)
      //Logger.log("unique"+countrangeunique)
      for (var a =0;a < countrangeunique.length;a++){
        var countnumber = 0;
        for (var b = 0; b < range.length;b++){
          if (range[b] !="" || range[b] !=[]){
          var rangeformated = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(range[b]),"GMT+1","M/d/yyy")
          Logger.log((datestart <= rangeformated) +":"+(rangeformated <= dateend))    
          if (datestart <= rangeformated && rangeformated <= dateend){
            Logger.log("activestore:"+countrangeunique[a]+" storescan:"+countrange[b]+"match:"+(countrange[b] == countrangeunique[a]))    
            if (countrange[b] == countrangeunique[a]) {
                  countnumber++
                  count[a][0] = countrangeunique[a] 
                  count[a][1] = countnumber
                  Logger.log("counternumber"+countnumber+" store: "+countrangeunique[a])
              }
          }
        }
      }
      }
```

so starting at the top is the count unique function to find the unique value in the store range i3:i..that is input through the variable "valuesrange". 
contained in that range are the store id numbers. for the stores the employee has worked ie 2512,1533.
the count date function looks for unique store ids. Then for each number checks the range of dates to be sure the dates are within this month. these are entered  with "datestart" ie beginning of the month. "dateend"ie end of the month. and daterange. the dates the employee has worked in format "m/d/yyy". if the dates are not inside the month or if they are blank they should be ignored and the system moves on to the next .  than it compares the unique number to the range of store numbers inside the month and should count them. however countrange[b] == countrangeunique[a] is not matching even if the values are the same. how can i fix this? right now my log shows.

[pastebinlog](https://pastebin.com/WnREzJ41)

Answer (score 0):

solution i fount was to force the js to parse the returned values as int using parseInt(value,10). good luck to anyone else having this problem.